# How can i make a carrousel with buttons and change slide when mouse over

Tags: carousel

im trying to make a carrousel like this

[LinK!](http://spanish.alibaba.com)

the carousel have buttons with the content of each slide and when u move the mouse over any button of the carousel, this change the slide, also have a timer to change the slide.

Im using bootstrap 3.2.0 this is what I have

HTML

```
    <div class="panel-body clearfix">
    <!-- LINKED NAV -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ol class="carousel-linked-nav pagination">
            <li class=""><a href="#1">4</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#2">3</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#3">2</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#4">1</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" class=" img-responsive " src="<?= IMG . '4.jpg' ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" class=" img-responsive " src="<?= IMG . '3.jpg' ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" class=" img-responsive " src="<?= IMG . '2.jpg' ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" class=" img-responsive " src="<?= IMG . '1.jpg' ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-indicators li{
   border: none;
   background-color: #888;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active{
   border: none;
   background-color: #4297d7;
}
#myCarousel {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
.carousel-linked-nav, .item img {
   display: inline; 
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel-linked-nav {
   width: 120px;
   margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

JS

```
function carousel() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    });
    $('.carousel-linked-nav > li > a').click(function() {
        var item = Number($(this).attr('href').substring(1));
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(item - 1);
        $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
    $('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
        $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');
        var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();
        $('.carousel-linked-nav li:eq(' + idx + ')').addClass('active');
    });
}
```

Im trying to make carousel like the link, and well i cant, the Carousel buttons use all the space in this, and when the mouse over a button change the slide

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks for adding code to your post. Now please add what's the problem with your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i resolve that adding this in the js

```
$('.carousel-linked-nav > li > a').mouseover(function() {
        var item = Number($(this).attr('href').substring(1));
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(item - 1);
        $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
```

so the basic problem i haven is i can't to make the buttons used all space of the carousel. I mean the width of the carousel and space is distributed among them.

Comment: You should include this into your question because an answer is the wrong place for remaining problem statements.